# How to get the path of a derived class from an inherited method?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, reflection

**How to get the path of the current class, from an inherited method?**

I have the following:

```
<?php // file: /parentDir/class.php
   class Parent  {
      protected function getDir() {
         return dirname(__FILE__);
      }
   }
?>
```

and

```
<?php // file: /childDir/class.php
   class Child extends Parent {
      public function __construct() {
         echo $this->getDir(); 
      }
   }
   $tmp = new Child(); // output: '/parentDir'
?>
```

The `__FILE__` constant always points to the source-file of the file it is in, regardless of inheritance.
I would like to get the name of the path for the derived class.

**Is there any *elegant* way of doing this?**

I could do something along the lines of `$this->getDir(__FILE__);` but that would mean that I have to repeat myself quite often. I'm looking for a method that puts all the logic in the parent class, if possible.

**Update:**
Accepted solution (by [Palantir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79456/palantir)):

```
<?php // file: /parentDir/class.php
   class Parent  {
      protected function getDir() {
         $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
         return dirname($reflector->getFileName());
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Using [`ReflectionClass::getFileName`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php) with this will get you the dirname the class `Child` is defined on.

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("Child");
$fn = $reflector->getFileName();
return dirname($fn);
```

You can get the class name of an object with [`get_class()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) :)

Answer (score 31):

Yes. Building on Palantir's answer:

```
   class Parent  {
      protected function getDir() {
         $rc = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
         return dirname($rc->getFileName());
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 17):

Don't forget, since 5.5 you can [use `class` keyword for the class name resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class), which would be a lot faster than calling `get_class($this)`. The accepted solution would look like this:

```
protected function getDir() {
    return dirname((new ReflectionClass(static::class))->getFileName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If you are using namespaces, make sure to change `new ReflectionClass(...)` with `new \ReflectionClass(...)`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using *Composer* for autoloading you can retrieve the directory without reflection.

```
$autoloader = require 'project_root/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use get_called_class() for PHP 5.3 and 5.4
$file = $autoloader->findFile(static::class);
$directory = dirname($file);
```

Comment: Mate, I have spent about 4 hours today searching for a way to do this without using Reflection!! Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to access the `$autoloader` class without having access to the autoload-require statement?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php // file: /parentDir/class.php
   class Parent  {
      const FILE = __FILE__;
      protected function getDir() {
         return dirname($this::FILE);
      }
   }
?>


<?php // file: /childDir/class.php
   class Child extends Parent {
      const FILE = __FILE__;
      public function __construct() {
         echo $this->getDir(); 
      }
   }
   $tmp = new Child(); // output: '/childDir'
?>
```

Please not that if you need to get the dir, directly use `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the directory as constructor arg. Not super elegant, but at least you don't have to work with reflection or composer.

Parent:

```
<?php // file: /parentDir/class.php
   class Parent  {
      private $directory;

      public function __construct($directory) {
          $this->directory = $directory;
      }

      protected function getDir() {
         return $this->directory;
      }
   }
?>
```

Child:

```
<?php // file: /childDir/class.php
   class Child extends Parent {
      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(realpath(__DIR__));
        echo $this->getDir(); 
      }
   }
?>
```