# Determine path of child class from parent WITHOUT reflection - Is it possible?

Tags: php, reflection, subclass

I need to determine file path of child class from its parent. So code like this:

```
abstract class Parent {

     /**
      * @injected $this->__construct()
      */
     protected $child_name = null;

     public function sayHi() {
         $path = ???;
         echo 'I am saying hi from file '.$path.'!';
     }

}

class ChildA extends Parent {}
class ChildB extends Parent {}

$a = new ChildA;
$b = new ChildB;

$a->sayHi();
$b->sayHi();
```

... would output this:

```
I am saying hi from file lib/childA/plugin.php!
I am saying hi from file lib/childB/plugin.php!
```

There are plenty answers for this particular problem, however each one **reflection methods** like this:

- [How to get the path of a derived class from an inherited method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014254/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-derived-class-from-an-inherited-method)

I was told, that you should never use reflection classes in production code. So right now, I am trying to figure out which way to go:

1) Convention over configuration: Hardcode expected child path to the function.

```
public function sayHi() {

    $path = 'lib/'.$this->child_name.'/plugin.php';

}
```

2) Having a property in each child class, that will use a magic constant. That seems a little dull however, as I will have A LOT of child classes.

```
class ChildA extends Parent {

    protected $path = __FILE__;

}
```

3) Setting for reflection methods after all.

4) Something you might suggest?

### Update

I am getting the file path to child class because by that, I need to include the file with default configuration of the class. The file with configuration only returns an `array`, so I can not use the `spl_autoload` functionality in here ...

### Update 2

To illustrate the actual problem:

```
| - Abstracts
|   | - APlugin.php
| - PluginStart
|   | - PluginStart.php
|   | - config.php
| - PluginTheme
|   | - PluginTheme.php
|   | - config.php
```

`SayHi()` method from APlugin.php should somehow find path to config.php for each child class.

### TL;DR

Is it possible to determine a path of child class from its parent without using the Reflection methods?

Sorry that I'm asking a question that was already answered (at least sort of)! And thanks for your time.

Comment: So it sounds like you're using autoloading and want to get the file path? Or do you simply want to get the class name/namespace?

Comment: By the file path to child class, I need to determine a location of a **different** file with default configuration of the child class, that only returns an array. That is why I can not use an Autoloader in this case ...

Comment: Ok, so are all these classes living in one giant file or one file per class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanest implementation is probably:

```
abstract class Parent {

    abstract protected function getPathToConfigFile();

    ...

}

class Child extends Parent {

    protected function getPathToConfigFile() {
        return __DIR__ . '/config';
    }

}
```

You shouldn't necessarily leave this up to implicit relationships in the file system, it may make the system too inflexible later on. Make everything that can be made explicit explicit.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely way to go, although I wanted to avoid specifiyng the function in **all child classes** (as there will be a lot of them). 

I will leave the question open for some time, if there will appear any DRIER way how to solve this, if not, I will take this route. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't know of a way to do it otherwise without reflection, which seems like the next sanest option. If you need to DRY this, I'd suggest implementing `getPathToConfigFile` to use `ReflectionClass` to get the path, and leave the method overloadable for maximum flexibility.

Comment: So it is "ok" to use reflection methods in production code? It is out of scope of this question, but I was not able to find a tangible answer to that either (except of big fat **no**).

Comment: If used in moderation I think it's ok. Reflection is basically a tool to do meta-programming, in which code can reason about code. You shouldn't go crazy with this, especially in PHP which isn't too terribly suited for meta-programming. However, to DRY some code which would otherwise be too repetitive it's fine IMO. I occasionally use it for sanity checks like checking if a value is one of the constants defined in a class and such things.

Comment: Thanks for going through all possible solutions with me! I think I will suck up some code repetition and settle for option 1 in the end - situations when the configuration files are located elsewhere may always occure, as you pointed out. Have a nice day!